# Training a new entity type with spacy

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

Need help to try adding new entity and train my own model with spacy named entity recognition. I wanted first to try the example already done here:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_new_entity_type.py

but i'am getting this error :

ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-c46f384e-5989-4902-a775-7618ffadd54e.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2890: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Tried to look into all related questions and answers and couldn't resolve this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Knowing that I tried this on colab.google.search (all on cloud) and got the same error

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running the code from a Jupyter notebook, right? All spaCy examples are designed as fully standalone scripts to run from the command line. They use the Python library `plac` for generating the command-line interface, so you can run the script with arguments. Jupyter however seems to add another command-line option `-f`, which causes a conflict with the existing command-line interface.

As a solution, you could execute the script directly instead, for example:

```
python train_new_entity_type.py
```

Or, with command line arguments:

```
python train_new_entity_type.py --model en_core_web_sm --n-iter 20
```

Alternatively, you could also remove the `@plac.annotations` and `plac.call(main)` and just execute the `main()` function directly in your notebook.

Comment: Thank you very much @InesMontani